# Array of drawables and if statement are not changing

Tags: android, arrays, imageview

I have a random class that opens a random `ImageView` when starting my activity. Every time I open the random image the text are constant with "بصل"

```
public class GiftsAct extends Activity {

ImageView im;
int imagesOfGifts [] = {
        R.drawable.thebasal,
        R.drawable.theboot,
        R.drawable.thecamera,
        R.drawable.thehandbag,
        R.drawable.thelap,
        R.drawable.thephone,
        R.drawable.thewatch,
};
Random imagesChoosing = new Random();
TextView greetingMessage;
TextView nameOfUser;
TextView giftName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gifts);



    im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int any = imagesChoosing.nextInt(7);
    im.setImageResource(imagesOfGifts[any]);
    giftName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.giftNAme);
    greetingMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theTextOfGreeting);
    nameOfUser = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NameOfThePersonIntent);

   /** // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/kharabeesh.ttfy";

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    greetingMessage.setTypeface(tf);
    nameOfUser.setTypeface(tf);
    **/

    Intent getSomeThing = getIntent();
    String valsOfName =  getSomeThing.getStringExtra("theName");
    nameOfUser.setText(valsOfName);



    if (imagesOfGifts[0] == R.drawable.thebasal)
        giftName.setText("بصل");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[1] == R.drawable.theboot)
        giftName.setText("شبشب");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[2] == R.drawable.thecamera)
        giftName.setText("كاميرا");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[3] == R.drawable.thehandbag)
        giftName.setText("شنطة نسائية");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[4] == R.drawable.thelap)
        giftName.setText("لابتوب");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[5] == R.drawable.thephone)
        giftName.setText("ايفون");

    else if (imagesOfGifts[6] == R.drawable.thewatch)
        giftName.setText("ساعة");





}
```

Comment: Can you post the full activity?

Comment: Isn't it because the first element is always the same and therefore satisfying the `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here...

```
int imagesOfGifts [] = {
        R.drawable.thebasal,
        R.drawable.theboot,
        R.drawable.thecamera,
        R.drawable.thehandbag,
        R.drawable.thelap,
        R.drawable.thephone,
        R.drawable.thewatch,
};
```

you have an array with these elements, which do not change as far as I can see.

Then you `if` the elements with...

```
if (imagesOfGifts[0] == R.drawable.thebasal)
    giftName.setText("بصل");
```

but `imagesOfGifts[0]` always `== R.drawable.thebasal`.

IOW, you may be randomizing the image in the view but not the elements in the array, hence you always satisfy the first `if`.

You could `switch` the random index to get rid of the `if` chain like...

```
switch(any) {
    case 0:
        giftName.setText("بصل");
        break;
    // continue with other cases
}
```

or do it as you are now...

```
if(any == 0)
    giftName.setText("بصل");   
else if ...
```

instead of...

```
if (imagesOfGifts[0] == R.drawable.thebasal)
    giftName.setText("بصل");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sparse int array (equivalent of a int hashmap or key value pairs) to do what you're attempting to do. You should externalize your strings into the strings.xml then you can create a sparse int array like this.

```
public class GiftsAct extends Activity{

  private static SparseIntArray gifts;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     gifts  = new SparseIntArray();
     gifts.append(R.drawable.thebasal, R.string.thebasal);
     gifts.append(R.drawable.theboot, R.string.theboot);
     //ect...
     //your code
     im.setImageResource(gifts.keyAt(any));
     // more of your code
     giftName.setText(gifts.valueAt(any));

   }
}
```

This way you won't have to use a large amount of if statements and you could potentially find a way to build the array dynamically with a loop.